# Bivariate Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics

Take T to be the triangular region in the plane with vertices at (−1, 0), (1, 0) and (0, 1) and suppose X and Y are jointly uniformly distributed in T.

(a) Find the marginal densities of X and Y
(b) Show X and Y are not independent
(c) Show Cov(X, Y ) = 0.

So I've got that the area of the triangle is 1. I've been given the hint that The marginal density fX(x) is given by different expressions on the intervals [-1,0] and [0,1].
So I split the shape in two each with an area of 1/2, finding the marginal for x on the positive side would be:
FXY(x,y)={2 x>0, y>0, x+y<1

Comment: Can you find and expression for the area of $T\cap(-\infty,x]\times\mathbb R$? For this discern the cases: $x<-1,-1\leq x<0, 0\leq x<1, 1\leq x$. It provided the CDF of $X$ and PDF can be found by differentiating.

Comment: Thanks for the response. the area for $$T∩(−∞,x]×R = (-1<x<1)*(0<y<1)/2 = 1.$$ Not sure why you  "×R". And why differentiate, I thought I would be finding the integral for marginal densities

Comment: $T$ and $(-\infty,x]\times\mathbb R$ are both subsets of the plane $\mathbb R^2$. The area of this intersection equals $F_X(x)=\Pr(X\leq x)$ and the derivative of $F_X$ can be used as density $f_X$ for $X$. This answers (a) for random variable $X$.

Comment: The area of the intersection I mentioned is an expression in variable $x$. It will take value $0$ if $x<-1$ (then the intersection is empty) and it will take value $1$ if $1\leq x$ (then the intersection is $T$, and the area of $T$ is $1$). You must find it for values in $x\in[-1,1)$.

Comment: Yeah! Thats what I need to find. So the area is 1 (1/2 for each side of the origin). so for the positive side I plug in 1/2 and intergrate between 0 and 1. Please tell me if I am on the right track and focus on the process as well as what I need to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact that the area of $T$ is $1$ we conclude that function
$1_{T}$ serves as PDF for $\left(X,Y\right)$.

Then: $$F_{X}\left(x\right)=\Pr\left(X\leq x\right)=\iint1_{T}\left(u,v\right)1_{\left(-\infty,x\right]}\left(u\right)dvdu=\iint1_{T}\left(u,v\right)1_{\left[-1,x\right]}\left(u\right)dvdu$$

If $x<-1$ then the integrand is $0$ so that in that case $F_{X}\left(x\right)=0$

If $x\geq1$ then $1_{T}\left(u,v\right)1_{\left[-1,x\right]}\left(u\right)=1_{T}\left(u,v\right)$
and we find $F_{X}\left(x\right)=\iint1_{T}\left(u,v\right)dudv=1$.

If $-1\leq x<0$ then: $$\iint1_{T}\left(u,v\right)1_{\left[-1,x\right]}\left(u\right)dvdu=\int_{-1}^{x}\int1_{T}\left(u,v\right)dvdu=\int_{-1}^{x}\int_{0}^{u+1}dvdu=$$$$\int_{-1}^{x}u+1du=\left[\frac{1}{2}u^{2}+u\right]_{-1}^{x}=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+x+\frac{1}{2}$$

Actually under $-1\leq x<0$ it is **more handsome** to make a picture
and to find on a basic way an expression in $x$ for the area of the triangle
$T_{x}:=T\cap\left(-\infty,x\right]\times\mathbb{R}$.

Observe now that as PDF on $-1\leq x<0$ you can take the derivative
of $F_{X}$ wich leads to $f_{X}\left(x\right)=x+1$.

Caution: the PDF will have a different look on $0\leq x<1$. That case I will leave up to you.

Comment: So a more handsome way to do the above would be $$for -1\leq x<0, area: y-x=1, so , y=x+1,fX(x)=\int_{0}^{y=x+1}1dx=[y]=x+1$$

Comment: Um so when I find the marginal of the other side 0<=x<1, what do I do with the result? Do I just add it to the above?

Comment: If you do it correctly then for $0\leq x<1$ you will find CDF $F_X(x)=-\frac12x^2+x+\frac12$ and PDF $f_X(x)=1-x$. Combined with what you know about the other cases we eventually conclude that $f_X(x):=\max(1-|x|,0)$ serves as PDF of $X$.

Comment: $$for\ 0\leq x<1 \text{ area is } y+x=1 \text{ so } y=1-x, \ fX(x)=\int_{y=1-x}^{0}1dx=[y]=-(1-x)=x-1$$

Comment: I really do not understand your way of finding the area. If you are really busy with finding it then you are actually busy with finding the CDF (not the PDF). Btw, there is a shortcut for finding the PDF of $X$. Triangle $T$ is included by the lines $y=x+1$ (that gives the PDF for $-1\leq x<0$) and $y=1-x$ (that gives the PDF for $0\leq x<1$).

Comment: Thus the confusion and lack of understanding both ways. I am finding the marginal by using the definition in "Mathematics Statistics 7th - Wackerly" 5.3 Let X and Y be jointly discrete random variables with probability function p(x, y). Then the marginal probability function of X is given by $$ fX(x)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x,y)dy$$

Comment: That looks good. For $0\leq x<1$ you then find $f_X(x)=\int_0^{1-x}1dy=1-x$. I don't call that "finding the area" though. By area I think of a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ such as $T$ or $T_x$.

Comment: The question still stands. The marginal density of X for -1<x<1

Comment: No, the answer is found: $1-|x|$. Outside that interval it takes value $0$. That's why I came up with $\max(1-|x|,0)$.

Comment: Thank you friend. I should be able to do the other questions. I will mark you answer as valid.

Comment: You are welcome. The direction I pointed you (determine CDF and then PDF by taking derivative) is okay, but in this case not the most efficient one. Wackerly was more direct.